# Ubercart add custom price product?

Tags: 6, hooks, ubercart

I want to add a Gift Card product to my Cart but assign a value the user typed in (so for example Product ID 3 would be gift card for $1, and I would then make it $25,$50, and so on).

How can I do this? I looked at uc_cart_add_item but it is just NID, and I don't want to make 500 different products for each amount possible.

Any help!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the Variable Price module?
http://drupal.org/project/uc_varprice

It's ostensibly for donations, but I think it might be customizable for your purpose.